# Unable to get row data in datatables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatable, datatables

**I am try to get the complete row data on click.**

I tried this code from Datatables official website -

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
                        data: data,
                        columns: [
                            { data: "UserID" },
                            { data: "Name" },
                            { data: "emailID" },
                            { data: "Role" },
                            { data: "Status" }
                        ]
                    } );

$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
                        var data = table.row(this).data();
                        alert( "Value = "+data[0] );
                    } );
```

But getting the Value = undefined.

Comment: Please attach MCVE code [https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Show more data and HTML please.

Comment: @MinhNguyen there is nothing to do with the html code in this.

Comment: Isn't it `table.on( 'click', 'tbody tr', function () { ...` ?

Comment: Can you check your console for any DataTables warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for this is -

Instead of -

```
alert( "Value = "+ data[0] );
```

We have to access it in this way because its an object -

```
alert( "Value = "+ data.UserID );
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize table object like this:

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
```

Comment: can you console  data ? console.log(data);  above this line  alert( "Value = "+data[0] );

Comment: Yes Niraj, data is coming in console in object form. How to separate it and store in different variables.

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone, I got the solution. I am posting the solution below.